# md-table with datasource not updating on delete

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-services, angular-material2

I have an angular component with a material design table where objects are shown. This component gets its data via a datasource. The datasource gets its data from a http-service. The table itself can be filtered.

That's my code, simplified - Feel free to ask for further information on certain things if you need to..

*customer.component.html*

```
<md-input-container floatPlaceholder="never">
    <input mdInput #filter placeholder="Filter customers">
</md-input-container>
<md-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource">
    <ng-container cdkColumnDef="customerid">
        <md-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef> ID </md-header-cell>
        <md-cell *cdkCellDef="let row"> {{row.id}} </md-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container cdkColumnDef="remove">
        <md-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef></md-header-cell>
        <md-cell *cdkCellDef="let row"> 
            <button md-button (click)="deleteCustomer(row)">
                Remove Customer
            </button> 
        </md-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <md-header-row *cdkHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns">
    </md-header-row>
    <md-row *cdkRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;">
    </md-row>
</md-table>
```

*customer.component.ts*

```
export class CustomerOverviewComponent implements OnInit {
    public displayedColumns: string[] = [
        "customerid", "remove"
    ];
    public dataSource: CustomerOverviewDataSource | null;
    @ViewChild("filter") filter: ElementRef;

     constructor(private dataService: CustomerOverviewService,
                 private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {
        this.initDataSource(dataService);
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        Observable.fromEvent(this.filter.nativeElement, "keyup")
            .debounceTime(150)
            .subscribe(() => {
                if (!this.dataSource) { return; }
                this.dataSource.filter = this.filter.nativeElement.value;
            });
    }

    public deleteCustomer(customer: CustomerOverview): void {
        this.dataSource.disconnect();
        this.dataService
            .Delete(customer.id)
            .subscribe(data => {
                this.error.info(`Customer with Id: ${data._body} deleted!`);
            }, (err) => {
                this.error.error(`Unable to delete customer: ${err.message}`);
            });
        this.dataSource.connect();
    }

    private initDataSource(dataService: CustomerOverviewService): void {
        this.dataSource = new CustomerOverviewDataSource(this.dataService);
    }
}
```

*customer.service.ts*

```
@Injectable()
export class CustomerOverviewService {
    private actionUrl: string;
    private headers: Headers;

    dataChange: BehaviorSubject<CustomerOverview[]> = new BehaviorSubject<CustomerOverview[]>([]);
    get data(): CustomerOverview[] { return this.dataChange.value; }

    constructor(private http: Http, private authHttp: AuthHttpService, public snackBar: MdSnackBar) {

        this.actionUrl = Configuration.API_SERVER + "api/customeroverview/";

        this.headers = new Headers();
        this.headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        this.headers.append("Accept", "application/json");
        this.GetAll().forEach(s => this.dataChange.next(s));
    }

    public GetAll = (): Observable<CustomerOverview[]> => {
        return this.authHttp
            .get(this.actionUrl)
            .map((response: Response) => <CustomerOverview[]>response.json())
            .publishReplay(1)
            .refCount();
    }

    public Delete = (id: number): Observable<any> => {
        return this.authHttp.delete(this.actionUrl + id)
            .catch(console.log("Delete Catch"));
    }
}

export class CustomerOverviewDataSource extends DataSource<any> {
    _filterChange = new BehaviorSubject("");
    get filter(): string { return this._filterChange.value; }
    set filter(filter: string) { this._filterChange.next(filter); }

    constructor(private dataService: CustomerOverviewService) {
        super();
    }

    /** Connect function called by the table to retrieve one stream containing the data to render. */
    connect(): Observable<CustomerOverview[]> {
        const displayDataChanges: any = [
            this.dataService.GetAll(),
            this._filterChange,];

        return Observable.merge(...displayDataChanges).map(() => {
            return this.dataService.data.slice().filter((item: CustomerOverview) => {
                let searchStr: string = (item.gender + item.lastname + item.firstname + item.personalnumber
                    + item.consultant + item.hasConsultingEntities).toLowerCase();
                return searchStr.indexOf(this.filter.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
            });
        });
    }

    disconnect(): void {
        console.log("disconnect");
    }
}
```

When I delete a entity from the table, it does not get updated. Where are the objects stored, so I can know what I have to update? I have the feeling that the objects, the HTML gets, are in the constant variable displayDataChanges and I cannot change this?

Thanks for any hints to the right directions..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close, but there are a few things slightly off here:

1. I don't know of a valid use case for calling `connect()` and `disconnect()` manually. AFAIK `connect()` should only be called once *by the table*, and `disconnect()` is a callback when the table is destroyed in case you need to do any sort of unsubscribing or other cleanup. You can remove those lines from `deleteCustomer()`.
2. `displayDataChanges` includes `dataService.GetAll()`. That means that when `connect()` is called by the table and the result is subscribed to, `GetAll()` will run. I doubt this is what you want, since `GetAll()` is already called and cached in the constructor of `CustomerOverviewService`. You probably want `dataService.dataChange`, the `BehaviorSubject`, to be part of the `displayDataChanges` instead. That means that whenever you call `dataChange.next(vals)`, your `connect()` Observable will emit a new value, and the table will be updated.
3. The state of your service does not change when `Delete()` is called. Whenever the request completes, you should advance the `BehaviorSubject` with `next()` to update `dataChange` with the new value. You can either sort through the current `data` and remove the entry, or you can call `GetAll()` again. In either case, `next()` the new results into `dataChange` so that the table will re-render.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that solved the issues and is explained very good. Somehow I didn't recognize displayDataChanges never gets updated once it was created